# Post parameters with php file_get_contents not sent

Tags: php, post, file-get-contents

I have this code:

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
            array(
                'file' => $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 
                'quality' => "75",
                'path' => "myfile.jpg",
                'dpi' => "300"
            )
        );
        $opts = array('http' =>
            array(
                'type' => "POST",
                'header' => "Content-type: multipart/form-data\r\nxhrFields: { withCredentials: true }\r\ncache: false\r\ncrossDomain: true\r\nprocessData: false\r\ncontentType: false" ,
                'content' => $postdata
            )
        );
        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        $result = file_get_contents('https://example.com/myphpfile.php', false, $context);
        echo $result;
```

In `myphpfile.php` I read the post file parameter in this way:

```
$pdf = $_POST["file"];
$dpi = $_POST["dpi"];
$quality = $_POST["quality"];
$path = $_POST["path"];

print_r($_POST);
```

And I get this response:

```
Notice: Undefined index: file in /var/www/html/example/myphpfile.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: dpi in /var/www/html/example/myphpfile.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: quality in /var/www/html/example/myphpfile.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: path in /var/www/html/example/myphpfile.php on line 17
Array ( )
```

I cannot understand what is going wrong.

Comment: `echo $result;` returns _null_?

Comment: @Skip it returns an empty string.

Comment: You're code has got some weird things. You use `'type' => "POST"`, which should be `'method' => "POST"` and when I use `'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` instead of your header, it works. Remember that the data you send is actually URL-encoded and does not contain multipart files.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware you are right, now it works